# Casting pointers and the ternary ?: operator. Have I reinvented the wheel?

Tags: c++, casting, ternary-operator

The last line of this code fails to compile with `castingAndTernary.cpp:15: error: conditional expression between distinct pointer types ‘D1*’ and ‘D2*’ lacks a cast`

A really smart compiler could have no difficulty because both can be safely casted to `B*` (the base class). I'm reluctant to use static_cast and dynamic_cast and so on - I'm worried that I'll mix up the classes someday and get undefined behaviour. That's why I created the up_cast template. This template does the bare minimum in allowed conversion. Is there a simpler way? There are other workarounds, but I can't help but think that there's something even simpler and safer that I could use?

```
struct B{ };
struct D1 : public B{ };
struct D2 : public B{ };

template<typename T,typename V>
T up_cast(V x) {
        return x;
}
int main() {
        bool boolean_expression = true;
        B * b;
        b = new D1;
        b = new D2;
        b = boolean_expression ? up_cast<B*>(new D1) : up_cast<B*>(new D2);
        b = boolean_expression ? new D1 : new D2;
}
```

g++ (Ubuntu 4.3.3-5ubuntu4) 4.3.3

**Update** changed name from `implicit_cast` to `up_cast` as per @Konrad's answer

Comment: The phrase "implicit cast" makes no sense. A cast is an explicit conversion.

Comment: For an even weider approach: `b = boolean_expression ? new D1 : (true? new D2 : (B*)0 );`

Comment: I believe your cast is functionally identical to a C-style cast.

Comment: @Tomalak, I got the word implicit from [here](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=312456) "'static_cast' allows to perform any casting that can be _implicitly_ performed as well as also the inverse cast (even if this is not allowed implicitly)." (My emphasis)

Comment: @Aaron McDaid: If you are to do that cast, I would recomment that you make the pointers explicit, so that it will fail if you try it on non-pointers (rather than potentially making copies). Consider `D1 d1; up_cast<B&>(d1);` that looks sensible, but will not do what you might expect: `template <typename T, typename U> T* up_cast( U* p ) { return p; }` should do the trick.

Comment: @Benjamin: *definitely not*. A C-style cast is extremely powerful and would allow down-cast, up-cast, and completely unrelated cast. This cast is specific, and *always* safe.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> A really smart compiler could have no difficulty because both can be safely casted to `B*`

Irrelevant. The standard *mandates* this behaviour. A really smart compiler behaves as observed.

The use of your custom cast is actually fine (and your reluctance for using an explicit cast is well-placed). However, I’d use a different name: `upcast` – since that’s happening here: a cast upwards in the inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: I'm curious as to why the compiler would be mandated to complain. Although I admit that it could get very complicated for the compiler in some cases; with multiple inheritance that would be many valid 'least-common-denominator' classes.

Comment: @Aaron: Well, to what type should the compiler perform the implicit conversion?

Answer (score 6):

The [ternary] conditional operator requires its second and third operands to have the same type.

```
b = boolean_expression ? new D1 : new D2;
```

You have the distinct types `D1*` and `D2*`. As the error message indicates, you have to ensure the correct type with an explicit conversion (i.e. a cast):

```
b = boolean_expression ? static_cast<B*>(new D1) : static_cast<B*>(new D2);
```

The standard says that compilers must require this (instead of just doing an implicit conversion), so that's what your compiler requires.

Comment: I think that he knows that, and is just asking for comments on his `implicit_cast<>` template...

Comment: @David: If true, he's off-topic and should go to codereview. :)

Answer (score 6):

I was not going to answer, but after posting the comment I thought, what the... it is an approach as any other:

```
int main() {
   bool condition = true;
   D1 d1;
   D2 d2;
   B * p = condition ? &d1 : (true? &d2 : p );
}
```

Basically abuse the ternary operator to extract the appropriate type. When the compiler processes the ternary operator it tries to determine whether the two operands can be *implicitly* converted to a common type <sup>1</sup>, and if so, it uses that common type as the type of the expression.

In the code above, the inner ternary operator: `true? &d2 : p` will try to match the type of the expression `&d2` with the type of `p`, it will find that there is a simple upcast that it can perform and will set the return type for that subexpression to `B*`. Note that because the condition is `true`, it will always yield `&d2`, even if it uses the third argument to determine the type.

The same operation is performed with the enclosing expression, where now the second argument is `&d1` (type `D1*`) and the type of the third argument is `B*`. Again, the conversion is trivial by upcasting `D1*`, and the type of the whole expression is `B*`.

Because all of the conversions are performed implicitly by the compiler, if you change the types of the pointers, and break the invariant that they can be implicitly converted, the compiler will tell you, solving the issue of throwing a `static_cast` in the middle of the ternary operator.

<sup>1</sup> The standard dictates a set of different conversions, depending on the types of the arguments. In the particular case of the two arguments being pointers (as is the case here) the conversions that are allowed are *pointer conversions* and *qualification conversions*.

Comment: I think you mean "if one operand can be converted to match the type of the other operand". I was surprised when you said "implicitly converted to a common type" as I find that confusing and it implies that `condition ? &d1 : &d2` should work out of the box. +1 for nice trick.

Comment: @Aaron: The situation is different. In David's case, only one of the argument is converted, to the type of the other. In your case, you require an exhaustive search of all base classes. The complexity (and trickiness) are definitely different.

Comment: @Aaron, @Matthieu: The standard dictates what conversions can be performed in each case. For the particular case of pointers, the conversions that are allowed are in the footnote <sup>1</sup>: *pointer conversions* and *qualification conversions*. While the compiler cannot apply *any* conversion to find a common type, the fact is that the result type can be of a different type than any of the arguments: `D1 const * cp; B * b; (condition ? cp : b);` The result of the ternary operation in that case is a `const B*` rvalue, which is neither the left nor right types.

Answer (score -1):

I just came across this problem, lose the casts and do it the *long* way is cleanest IMO

```
B * d1 = new D1();
B * d2 = new D2();
B * b = boolean_expression ? d1 : d2;
```