# Odd C# Ternary Operator Behavior

Tags: c#, ternary-operator

So  I came across some very baffling behavior of the native ternary operator in C# today.  The ternary operator is sending the wrong data type to the method I'm calling.  The basic premise is I want to convert the decimal value to an `int` if `decimalEntry == false` so it will get stored in a database as an `int`  Here is the code:

```
decimal? _repGroupResult = 85.00
int? intValue = null;
bool decimalEntry = false;

if (decimalEntry == false)
{
    intValue = (int?) _repGroupResult;
}

Console.WriteLine("Sending to ResultAdd via ternary operator");
RepGBParent.ResultAdd(this.RepInfo.ResultID, decimalEntry ? _repGroupResult : intValue);

Console.WriteLine("Sending to ResultAdd via if statement");
// All other tests - just add the rep group result
if (decimalEntry)
{
    RepGBParent.ResultAdd(this.RepInfo.ResultID, _repGroupResult);
}
else
{
    RepGBParent.ResultAdd(this.RepInfo.ResultID, intValue);
}
```

The method I'm calling `ResultAdd` is here:

```
public void ResultAdd(int pResultID, object pResultValue)
{
    if (pResultValue == null) { return; } 

    Console.WriteLine(this.TestInfo.TestNum + ": " + pResultValue.GetType());
    ....
}
```

The ternary operator receives a `decimal` while the `if` statement sends an `int`.  As shown by the output code below:

[image]

I consider myself a programmer of reasonable talent and this really threw me back today.  I played around with it for 2-3 hours and figured out the best way to post it here so I'm clear of the issue I'm having.

Please avoid "why are you even doing it that way" type responses.  I simply want to know why there is a difference here between the ternary operator and the if statement.

The only other post that I found that was closely related was this one but it didn't quite match up:

[Bizarre ternary operator behavior in debugger on x64 platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067354/bizarre-ternary-operator-behavior-in-debugger-on-x64-platform)

Comment: I hate it when people do this if (bool == false).  Use if(!bool) !!!!  However not as bad as if(bool == true).

Comment: @JSON - and I hate it when people come on here and critique code when it makes zero difference if you use `if (!bool)` or `if (bool == false)` from a functionality standpoint.  It is personal preference plain and simple and all a matter of readability.  Some people feel `!` is more readable than `== false`, some don't.  I personally feel `== false` is  more straight forward to understand when reviewing code.  Easy to miss a single `!` symbol.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The ternary operator is - well - an *operator* which is only a special kind of method. And as any other method, it can only have **one single return type**.

What you try to do is to use the operator to return a `decimal?` **or** an `int?` depending on a condition. That is not possible.

What happens is that the compiler knows that there is an implicit conversion from `int?` to `decimal?`, but not the other way round. So it infers the *return type of the operator* as `decimal?` and implicitly converts your `intValue` into a `decimal?`.

Comment: C# seems to inherit this behavior from C [just like C++ does](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6179455/5922757).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.  I should have been able to figure this out myself.  It is Friday and it is time for a cocktail!

Answer (score 4):

The ternary expression returns a single type, not a type conditional on the result of the evaluation.

Your int is promoted to decimal in order to fullful that requirement.

If the conversion could not be applied, you would get a complier error.

> Either the type of first_expression and second_expression must be the same, or an implicit conversion must exist from one type to the other.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx